# How can I trace if someone is using my SoundCloud ClientID and making automated "play" requests?

Tags: soundcloud

I have made a **hobby, non-profit, free** app that aggregated Myanmar (my nationality) songs from SoundCloud and let my country-man listen more conveniently through my App.

And recently, I have discovered the `"play" requests (/tracks/:id/stream)` from my App is experiencing `Reaching Rate Limit` error from SoundCloud.

I know SoundCloud has 15K request limit per ClientID in a day. And my App only has about **10K total playbacks** in a day.

I'm suspect that someone is using my ClientID and making `**automated** "play" requests` to SoundCloud. My question is - is there any way that I can trace the origins of my ClientID's `"play" requests` ?

Comment: I'm quite sure you can't trace this by yourself. You have to probably ask them.

Comment: By the way, are you sure that your app is only doing 10k total playbacks in a day?

Comment: @GoingSolo, yes. very sure. I have my play request logged in Fabric. And that's why I'm asking with #soundcloud tag. And hoping they will be a bit considerate. :)

Comment: Unfortunately the api key is too easy to steal, since it is passed as a parameter in every request. They should logging all the requests for audit purpose tho, so it’s not hard to trace the ip source.